# Angular2 - toggle another element based on an event from a child component

Tags: angular, toggle

I have a component which has this child:

```
<fb-customer-list (inSearchMode)="listIsInSearchMode = event$"></fb-customer-list>
```

As you can see, it listens to an event from that child, which is just a boolean value (indicates whether the child changed modes).

In the parent, I am trying to hide a div based on this boolean:

```
<div class="center fade" *ngIf="!listIsInSearchMode">
```

But this only works the first time the boolean changes. After that, this div is always hidden. I know that ngIf removes directly from the DOM, but surely when the event becomes true again, it should be re-added.

I also tried applying `style.visibilty` based on the bool, and also using the `hidden` attribute...but both give the same result.

I can see the event changing from true to false in the child, but it seems after the first time the parent does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you should write **$event** and not **event$**.

Is the div having the *ngIf is wraping the fb-customer-list component? If so, You can't listen to callback from children that are not 'alive'.

Comment: Thanks, something so obvious but I could not see the wood from the trees! $event is the fix, thank you so much :)